# Creation an array that represents new position (xyz) in 3D

Tags: python, arrays, 3d, position, photon

By using Python:

If we have a certain number of photons, let's say 100 photons, which propagate for a distance 10 cm between transmitter and receiver in 3 dimensions(xyz) straight down the z axis where the initial position is (0,0,1).While propagating, some random photons are randomly deflected by random scattering angles (theta, phi). Theta has random value between 0 and Pi, and phi has this value (2*Pi*S) where is uniform random value between 0 and 1.

Then, if we have an array ( let’s call it C_array) which represents random new x y z position.

What is the best method to ask this C_array if it is have any photon in it ( in the position which it represents)?
(We ask this C_array that is there any photon in you or not?
If yes, how many photons do you have out of 100? If no, print (NO)).

Could you plz write this code?

Thank you

...........

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don't ask us to write code for you, ask us to help you. 
Please try coding it yourself and come back to us if you have problems. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here we do not write code for you, yet we would like to help you - write *your own* code and ask here if you encounter any problems whatsoever